# Batch: Output Reg Query into CSV results

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, command-line-interface

I'm having a difficult time formatting a batch to output reg query results into a CSV file fields.

Raw script:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (\\localhost\C$\users\myusername\desktop\servers2.txt) do (
  echo %%a
  reg query "\\%%a\HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM\BIOS" /v "SystemSKU"
  reg query "\\%%a\HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM\BIOS" /v "SystemProductName"
  wmic /node:%%a bios get serialnumber
)>>testing.csv
pause
```

I need the results from each query to enter into the cells from left to right. The first "echo %%a" is the PC hostname from the servers2.txt.

Is there anyone who could lead me into the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42521299.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
for /f %%a in (%filename1%) do (
  FOR /L %%s IN (1,1,4) DO SET "col%%s="
  SET col1=%%a
  FOR /f "tokens=2*delims= " %%s IN ('reg query "\\%%a\HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM\BIOS" /v "SystemSKU"') DO SET col2=%%t
  FOR /f "tokens=2*delims= " %%s IN ('reg query "\\%%a\HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM\BIOS" /v "SystemProductName"') DO SET col3=%%t
  FOR /f "delims=" %%t IN ('wmic /node:%%a bios get serialnumber 2^>nul') DO SET col4=%%t
  ECHO !col1!,!col2!,!col3!,!col4!
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42521299.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Reads the file for servernames to `%%a` then establishes `col1` to `col4` with the required data and `echo`es it, using delayedexpansion.

The `reg query` lines are parsed using space-delimiters, dropping the first two tokens and retaining the rest of the line.

The `wmic` line yielded an error message (invalid option) on my system, so I aded `2>nul` to dispose of the error message.

This procedure creates the output anew. You're aware of the changes should you simply wish to append to a current file.

Comment: Thank you so much. That does exactly what I want. The only issue is its not outputting the serial number result. I appreciate your help! You're a time saver!

Comment: I'd also like to note that the get serial does work if I were to type it normally. I mention this to clear up any confusion whether the manufacture input it or not.

Comment: Worked happily for me if I use `/node:localhost`. Possibly I specified `%%a` incorrectly in the file - although the `reg query` appeared to work with my file-setting.

Comment: Hi Magoo, in regards to my last comment, i was able to resolve my last issue by changing the code to:
"  FOR /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%t IN ('wmic /node:%%a bios get serialnumber /format:list') DO SET col4=%%t"

Basically the tokens, delims and using /format:list

I appreciate all of your help! Your code helped me a ton!